# Can not add resource (com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@4ba9af2)

Tags: android

Can not add resource (com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@4ba9af2) to table.,Can not add resource (com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@851ebd) to table.,Can not add resource (com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@458790c9) to table.,Can not add resource (com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@243556a9) to table.

Facing the issue related to resources

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error can occur due to the fact that you have overwritten the default system attribute name in /attrs or /styles.

For example, you can't use the name "divider" in `<attr name="divider" format="reference" />`  because it causes a conflict with the system's default properties.

Instead change the name to something like `<attr name="myDivider" format="reference" />`  to avoid conflicts.

Comment: typical non sense android error message though. thanks for your answer